# While having WordPress site, how do I make a custom php web page viewable outside the WordPress environment?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site where a client wanted to add a custom web page (ex. custompage.php) so that they go to example.com/custompage. This custom page is just HTML and not related to WordPress, but simply making that page with that address goes to a 404 error in WordPress. How do I allow custom web pages to be viewed before having a WordPress check, so to speak?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Are you trying to create a custom page template?

Comment: If you don't include the .php extension in the URL, WordPress will load and try to find a post/page/CPT with that slug. When it doesn't find it, a 404 error message will be thrown (as you already know.) Including the .php extension in the URL (example.com/custompage.php) should load your .php file just fine.

Comment: You deleted your question: "PHP MySQL Update with 0 Affected Rows", without ever responding to our comments. Did you resolve the problem? What was it? Just curious. Was it the unnecessary JOIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you could add WP template tags on top of your PHP file so that WordPress will understand its a page template.

The file `custompage.php` must be inside your Custom/Child theme directory.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: custompage
 *
 */?>
<html><head></head><body>
<p>Your html...<p>
```

Then in WordPress dashboard, create a new page with the title `custompage` to make sure the slug is generated as wanted but it can be edited.

For this new page, in page attributes, select the newly created page template `custompage` and publish it.

You will be able to access example.com/custompage with your beautifull html displaying.

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you!